# Removing value from a comma seperated list with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having difficulty using regex to remove a value from a comma seperated list; the value could be anywhere in the list, my current solution which doesn't seem to work is:

```
var val = "455";
    sList = sList
        .replace(new RegExp("\b"+val,""))
        .replace(new RegExp("\b"+val+",(.+)"),"$1")
        .replace(new RegExp("\b(.+),"+val),"$1")
        .replace(new RegExp("(.*),"+val+",(.+)"),"$1,$2");
```

List could be:

```
var sList ="455" || "val1,val2,455,val4,valn" || "455,val2,val3,valn" || "val1,val2,val3,455";
```

Could anyone advise?

Many thanks, Alex

Comment: Do you need to use regex?  This can be done very easily without it.

Comment: @JNYRanger Don't need to use Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JNYRanger suggests it, it is more simple to split your string with commas, to remove the value and then to join the resulting array with comma:

```
var str= "val1,val2,455,val4,valn";

str = str.split(',').filter(function (i) { return i !== '455' }).join(',');
```

To do it with regex, you can simply list all possibilities like this:

```
/^455(?:,|$)|,455(?=,|$)/
```

Example:

```
var re = new RegExp("^" + val + "(?:,|$)|," + val + "(?=,|$)");

str = str.replace(re, '');
```

Comment: How about `/[^,]+/` instead of `^445(?:,|$)|,445(?=,|$)`?

Comment: @bjfletcher: No, you can't use this because the value is known in advance and fixed. It's only an illustration for `new RegExp("^" + val + "(?:,|$)|," + val + "(?=,|$)")`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Many thanks for your help; my preference is also to RegEx - really great help. Thanks to everyone here who has contributed. Regards Alex

Answer (score 1):

Some people like to use `split` and `join`:

```
var keep = [];
"val1,val2,455,val4,valn".split(",").forEach(function(val) {
  if (val !== "455") keep.push(val);
});
keep.join(",");
```

will yield:

```
"val1,val2,val4,valn"
```

Others, like me, would prefer to use regex's `match` instead, replacing `split(",")` above with `match(/[^,]+/g)`.

Comment: Ah you beat me to it.  I had this exact thing typed out!  Take an upvote.

Comment: @JNYRanger I feel really bad when that happens, it'd be nice if there was a more social way of answering.